# jquery ui tabs close button beneath the text

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I m using jquery ui tabs

and i m using them with the function of dynamically closing them.

the example page [here](http://pradyut.dyndns.org/WebApplicationSecurity/closetab.jsp) where clicking on the link 'add tab' leads to

adding of tabs in the tabs panel...

now in **firefox** the close buttons are displayed beneath the text of the tab

which is leading to garbled text in the tab panel or the body of the tabs

**like other browsers how can i display it in same line**

the css i m using is

```
     .ui-tabs { padding: .20em; zoom: 1; }
    .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav { list-style: none; position: relative; padding: .2em .2em 0; height:27px;  }
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li { position: relative; float: left; border-bottom-width: 0 !important; margin: 0 .2em -1px 0; padding: 0; font-size:63.5%;  }
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a { float: left; text-decoration: none; padding: .5em 1em;  }
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-selected { padding-bottom: 1px; border-bottom-width: 0;  }
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-selected a, .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-disabled a, .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-processing a { cursor: text;  }
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a, .ui-tabs.ui-tabs-collapsible .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-selected a { cursor: pointer; font: 62.5%; }
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel { padding: 1em 1.4em; display: block; border-width: 0; background:black; color:white; font-size: 12px; }
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide { display: none !important; font: 62.5%; }

#tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a:hover { float: left; text-decoration: none; padding: .5em 1em; background-color: #868472; }
#tabs-profile .ui-tabs-nav li { position: relative; float: left; border-bottom-width: 0 !important; margin: 0 .2em -1px 0; padding: 0; font-size:75%; }
```

Please help

thanks
Pradyut
India

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.ui-icon-close { float: left;}
```