# Jquery Tab header in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

I am trying to implement the Jquery ui Tabs # simple manipulation.

http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/tabs/manipulation.html

The close icon appears in the next line to the Text. it happens in firefox, not in chrome.
in firefox the tab tile is

[titleText 
 x]

In chrome it is 
[ titleText  x]

below is the li tag.

```
    <li ><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close' role='presentation'>R</span></li>
```

Please help if someone knows what is the css property causing this wrap of the li content.

thanks
Sachin

Comment: Likely related to default browser CSS if you aren't using a CSS normalizer or reset. Impossible to determine much without seeing a demo that replicates problem

Comment: Hi, I agree without demo its too difficult. I found a solution in post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753348/jquery-ui-tabs-close-button-beneath-the-text

Comment: Works fine in Firefox Developer Edition(36.0a2 (2014-12-26))

Answer (score 0):

Found solution in the post 
[jquery ui tabs close button beneath the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753348/jquery-ui-tabs-close-button-beneath-the-text)

added below to the jquery_ui.css

.ui-icon-close { float: left; }

thanks
Sachin